# Python split a string then regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm kinda stuck on a basic probleme but I really need your help here.
Here I get a sentence from an rss feed where I want to extract the grade which is either at the end or non existant
`grades = thefeedentry.get("title", "").split(" ")`
So I split it and here is what I get :
`['Séance1', ':', '9.25/20']`
and now I need to get the '9,25' and I think that I should do it using regex so I used grades as an array :

```
for grade in grades
                x = re.findall("/20$", grade)
                print(x)
```

and here I get an error without any specification :/ I think that it come from my for loop but I'm stuck and it since a while

Comment: No need for a regex: `print ( grades[-1].split('/')[0] )`

Comment: You forgot `:` after your loop definition: `for grade in grades:`

Comment: May it be you have forgotten an `:` while declaring loop?

Answer (score 1):

To get the number from the list you provided, just get the last item and split with `/` and grab the first item:

```
print ( grades[-1].split('/')[0] )
```

You may extract the number between `:` and `/` with the regex directly from your string:

```
import re
text = "Séance1 : 9.25/20"
m = re.search(r':\s*(\d[\d.]*)/', text)
if m:
    print ( m.group(1) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/US0G88). You may add logic to handle a case when the number is not found.

**Regex details**

- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 1: a digit and then 0 or more digit or `.` chars
- `/` - a `/` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5iRrO/1).

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
import re
title = "Seance1' : 9.25/20"
re.search(r'(?<=(\:\s))[\d\.]+(?=[\/])', title).group()
```

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kVjH1E/1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for Regex here.

This should work..

```
grades[-1].split('/')[0]
```

Here we try to get the values at last index of ['Séance1', ':', '9.25/20'] i.e. 9.25/10

```
 grades[-1]
```

We split the 9.25/10 on occurrence of '/' by using split function so we get [9.25, 10].

```
split('/')
```

Then we select 0th index of the previous step, hence we get 9.25.